# Algorithm for Fogbugz pricing scheme

Tags: c#, linq, algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm to calculate total cost of licenses purchased based on the "FogBugz for your server" pricing scheme (http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/PriceList.html).

Fogbugz pricing is:

- 1 License $299
- 5 License Pack    $999
- 10 License Pack   $1,899
- 20 License Pack   $3,499
- 50 License Pack   $7,999

If you ask a quote for let's say 136 licenses they calculate it as $22,694.

How can I do this in C# or LINQ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is you need help with? Are you trying to figure out how they pick the appropriate pricing scheme for values that are above the standard packages (51+ licenses)?

Comment: Kind of a strange question (or way to go about asking it with specific reference to FogBugz...) but I'm not sure it needs to be voted down...

Comment: See the OP's [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684261/how-to-convert-a-number-to-a-range-of-prices).

Comment: this is especially interesting since for certain edge cases, it will actually be cheaper to buy more licenses than the number you require.  I don't believe any of the algorithms thus far handle this.  I haven't crunched the numbers to see when/if this happens with the given prices, but in the general case it happens a lot.  I once ordered (real life) 25 microprocessors because I needed 20 and the price break at 25 made it cheaper to get all 25.

Comment: @rmeador: It could be a opportunity to suggest an upsell as well. "If you buy 10 more licenses, you'll get them for 60% off the individual price"

Comment: if I did my math right (which sadly I lost when I refreshed the page... it was in firebug's console), it is cheaper to buy 150 licenses ($23997) than 149 ($25191)

Comment: @Greg: that isn't really an upsell... assuming the salesperson wants to maximize the profits, he would try to upsell the customer if they're in the "normal" zone, but for the edge cases I'm talking about he'll actually want the customer to buy only the exact number they need.

Comment: @remeador: I meant if you're not in a edge case, sorry. Like 136 is cheaper than 150, so you can suggest they buy the extra 14 licenses at $93 each now. You get $1,300 more in your pocket now or *maybe* get $3,100 later. It's a business decision certainly, and I'm not sure which is better.

Comment: @Greg it's generally always best to offer the customer the most value for their dollar that if I received a request for a quote for 136 licenses I'd certainly point out that if they get the extra 14 now they will save almost 60% to get them upfront as opposed to adding them piecemeal afterwards, especially for an order of that size being only 10% more.

Comment: @rmeador: You're right - there are edge cases here. A good example is that it is cheaper to buy 5 licenses than 3 or 4. I've added an answer that handles this situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The accepted answer, whilst an elegant piece of code from a programmer's point of view, does not give the best possible price for the customer and therefore might not be an elegant solution from the customer's point of view. For example when n = 4, the accepted answer gives $1196, but a customer would obviously prefer to choose the 5 license pack and pay just $999 instead.

It is possible to construct an algorithm which can calculate the minimum price possible that the customer can pay to purchase their required number of licenses. One way of doing this is to use dynamic programming. I think something like this might do the trick:

```
int calculatePrice(int n, Dictionary<int, int> prices)
{

    int[] best = new int[n + prices.Keys.Max()];
    for (int i = 1; i < best.Length; ++i)
    {
        best[i] = int.MaxValue;
        foreach (int amount in prices.Keys.Where(x => x <= i))
        {
            best[i] = Math.Min(best[i],
                best[i - amount] + prices[amount]);
        }
    }
    return best.Skip(n).Min();
}

void Run()
{
    Dictionary<int, int> prices = new Dictionary<int, int> {
        { 1, 299 },
        { 5, 999 },
        { 10, 1899 },
        { 20, 3499 },
        { 50, 7999 }
    };

    Console.WriteLine(calculatePrice(136, prices));
    Console.WriteLine(calculatePrice(4, prices));
}
```

Output:

```
22694
999
```

---

**Update** Producing a breakdown is a little more complicated, but I definitely think it will be beneficial for your customers. You could do it something like this (assuming printing to the console, although a real program would probably output to a web page):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static Dictionary<int, int> prices = new Dictionary<int, int> {
            { 1, 299 },
            { 5, 999 },
            { 10, 1899 },
            { 20, 3499 },
            { 50, 7999 }
    };

    class Bundle
    {
        public int Price;
        public Dictionary<int, int> Licenses;
    }

    Bundle getBestBundle(int n, Dictionary<int, int> prices)
    {
        Bundle[] best = new Bundle[n + prices.Keys.Max()];
        best[0] = new Bundle
        {
            Price = 0,
            Licenses = new Dictionary<int, int>()
        };

        for (int i = 1; i < best.Length; ++i)
        {
            best[i] = null;
            foreach (int amount in prices.Keys.Where(x => x <= i))
            {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle
                {
                     Price = best[i - amount].Price + prices[amount],
                     Licenses = new Dictionary<int,int>(best[i - amount].Licenses)
                };

                int count = 0;
                bundle.Licenses.TryGetValue(amount, out count);
                bundle.Licenses[amount] = count + 1;

                if (best[i] == null || best[i].Price > bundle.Price)
                {
                    best[i] = bundle;
                }
            }
        }
        return best.Skip(n).OrderBy(x => x.Price).First();
    }

    void printBreakdown(Bundle bundle)
    {
        foreach (var kvp in bundle.Licenses) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,2} * {1,2} {2,-5} @ ${3,4} = ${4,6}",
               kvp.Value,
                kvp.Key,
                kvp.Key == 1 ? "user" : "users",
                prices[kvp.Key],
                kvp.Value * prices[kvp.Key]);
        }

        int totalUsers = bundle.Licenses.Sum(kvp => kvp.Key * kvp.Value);

        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("{0,7} {1,-5}           ${2,6}",
            totalUsers,
            totalUsers == 1 ? "user" : "users",
            bundle.Price);
    }

    void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("n = 136");
        Console.WriteLine();
        printBreakdown(getBestBundle(136, prices));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("n = 4");
        Console.WriteLine();
        printBreakdown(getBestBundle(4, prices));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().Run();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
n = 136

 2 * 50 users @ $7999 = $ 15998
 1 * 20 users @ $3499 = $  3499
 1 * 10 users @ $1899 = $  1899
 1 *  5 users @ $ 999 = $   999
 1 *  1 user  @ $ 299 = $   299
-------------------------------
    136 users           $ 22694


n = 4

 1 *  5 users @ $ 999 = $   999
-------------------------------
      5 users           $   999
```

Comment: Mark, this is an excellent idea... If I could get the breakdown of the proposed solution, so I can explain to the customer why is cheaper for them, will be awesome.

Comment: @Anon1865: Added an example of how you could give the customer a breakdown. To show why it is cheaper you would have to have something to compare it to. You could create a similar breakdown for the other algorithm and show how much they save, or perhaps try to advertise that you are giving them 5 licenses instead of 4 at no extra cost. Anyway hopefully I've given you enough to get started.

Comment: This seems like overkill. I'm fairly sure a simple greedy scheme works fine for this price schedule if you just set the cutoffs correctly.

Comment: @Nick Johnson: You mean like Neil G's solution? Sure, but if you do that you'd also have to remember to change the cutoffs if you adjust the prices. The above automatically does all the calculations for you - all you have to do is change the prices.

Comment: You can calculate the cutoffs from the prices, too, trivially.

Comment: @Nick Johnson: Maybe I'm missing something but I'm not sure it's as trivial as you suggest. How would you calculate it for 60 users? 50 + 10 or 20 + 20 + 20? Which of these is best depends on the prices. Could you post the code that calculates the "cutoffs" and how that can be used to correctly select the best package?

Answer (score 11):

```
int licenses = 136;
int sum = 0;

while (licenses > 0)
{
    if (licenses >= 50)      { sum += 7999; licenses -= 50; }
    else if (licenses >= 20) { sum += 3499; licenses -= 20; }
    else if (licenses >= 10) { sum += 1899; licenses -= 10; }
    else if (licenses >= 5)  { sum += 999;  licenses -= 5; }
    else                     { sum += 299;  licenses -= 1; }
}

// sum == 22694
```

or

```
int licenses = 136;
int sum = 7999 * Math.DivRem(licenses, 50, out licenses)
        + 3499 * Math.DivRem(licenses, 20, out licenses)
        + 1899 * Math.DivRem(licenses, 10, out licenses)
        +  999 * Math.DivRem(licenses,  5, out licenses)
        +  299 * licenses;

// sum == 22694
```

Comment: I was just trying to type up a similar answer.

Comment: +1, although a division-based algorithm would be more efficient for those customers buying squillions of licenses ;)

Comment: @Kent Boogaart: Answer expanded to accommodate for squillions of licenses. Change `int` to `long` for giga-squillions of licenses.

Comment: Second solution is one of the most elegant things I have ever seen. Excellent work.

Comment: `Math.DivRem`: for all your FogBugz-license-like needs

Answer (score 1):

Mark's solution is a great general solution, and definitely what you should go with (in case prices ever change.) This solution combines the simplicity of dtb's with the correctness of the Mark's:

```
int licenses = 136;
int sum = 7999 * Math.DivRem(licenses, 50, out licenses)
        + 7999 * Math.DivRem(licenses, 46, out licenses)
        + 3499 * Math.DivRem(licenses, 20, out licenses)
        + 1899 * Math.DivRem(licenses, 10, out licenses)
        +  999 * Math.DivRem(licenses,  5, out licenses)
        +  999 * Math.DivRem(licenses,  4, out licenses)
        +  299 * licenses;
```

It looks like the only edge cases are 5 is better than 4, and 50 is better than 46...49.  Although, realistically, you should probably suggest 50 when someone looks for 45, since the extra 5 licenses only cost $2.  So, maybe chnage 46 to 45 in the code.